# How do I send the data to API with encrypted data and signature with private key generated by RSA

Tags: c#, node.js, vue.js

I am C# developer and I have the below code works well in C# application. I am trying to use the same functionality in the VueJS and Node Js application. I have done with serialization and conversion to fromBase64String, but I am stuck here with generating signature to send it to API. please suggest.

```
byte[] privateKey = Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(appConfig.PrivateKey));
            using (CngKey signingKey = CngKey.Import(privateKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob))
            using (RSACng rsaCng = new RSACng(signingKey))
            {
                request.Data.Signature = Convert.ToBase64String(rsaCng.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.Data.Content), HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1));
            }
            var response = (Response)SendRequest(request, 1);
            return response;
```

I have tried the below in Vue and node Js  code

```
var utf8 = (encodeURIComponent(serializedProductInfo));

      var dataInfo = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < utf8.length; i++) {
        dataInfo.push(utf8.charCodeAt(i));
      }
       let base64Contenet = window.btoa((encodeURIComponent(dataInfo)));
      //let base64Contenet =  Buffer.toString((encodeURIComponent(dataInfo)));
      console.log(base64Contenet);

      var privateKey = [];
      privateKey = Buffer.from("My PrivateKey", "base64");
      var crypto = require('crypto');
      var sha1 = crypto.createHash('sha1');
      sha1.key = privateKey;
      sha1.update(dataInfo);
      var hash = sha1.digest();

      var signature = crypto.privateEncrypt({ key: privateKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, hash);
      console.log(signature);
```

I am getting the below error

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '2')"
```